# Half of data lost on JSON conversion?

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have a mysql database of countries, 250 in total, which in want to give over to an Android app. I know i have to use php in between to parse the result into JSON. This is it:

```
<?php 

 require_once('connection.php');
 $response = array();
 $resultarray = array();
 $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM countries");

 if (!empty($result)) {
    // check for empty result
    while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        print $row;
        $resultarray = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
        $Laender = array();
        $Countries[de] = $resultarray["de"];
        $response["Countries"] = array();

    array_push($response["Countries"], $Countries);

    echo json_encode($response);
    }
}       

?>
```

I ran the script in my browser and it displays correctly, except that half the countries are missing. There are only 125 countries displayed. Where have they vanished to?

Comment: Why do you call `mysqli_fetch_assoc` __and__ `mysqli_fetch_array`?

Comment: I am still new to php and after some test I did not notice a difference. The whole script is basically something i have cobbled together from various tutorials. Its probably not the issue though, is it?

Comment: I don't see any relationship with Android here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both functions `mysqli_fetch_assoc` **and** `mysqli_fetch_array` do the same - they fetch **next** record.

So, in your `while` you fetch **first** record with `mysqli_fetch_assoc` and then immediately fetch **second** record with `mysqli_fetch_array`. So, the **first** record is lost. And this happens on **every** iteration, so half of your records are lost.

Get rid of `mysqli_fetch_array` call:

```
$response["Countries"] = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    array_push($response["Countries"], $row["de"]);
}
echo json_encode($response);
```